# How to fix require.ensure error Webpack, Babel6, React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I trying to use require.ensure to create a chunk for Facility.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
class Facility extends Component {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.state = {
              ....
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                      ....
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Facility;
//Tried module.exports = Facility;
```

**NonPatientSer.js**

```
var Facility;
require.ensure([], function(require) { Facility = require('./Facility'); }, 'facility');
```

**Dev**
I can see facility.bundle.js in my sources but the call for it returns *undefined* and this errors

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of
>   `NonPatientSer`

and

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of
>   `NonPatientSer`.

**Production** (run build)

> Not allowed to load local resource:
>   file:///C:/Users/.../facility.bundle.js

**Webpack config**

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath:  __dirname + '/',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
```

Comment: How are you using `NonPatientSer`? Note that `require.ensure` is async so it's expected `Facility` will be `undefined` initially. If your code doesn't take this into account, it might very well fail the way you described.

Comment: @bebraw NonPatientSer is included into the main bundle.js file and does load when the application starts (I'm not sure what exactly do you mean).  Exactly what I want to achieve that this file will be included in the application as a separate file. In the Webpack documentation I've found this [link](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html)[/link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to fix **publicPath** property in your webpack.config. You should use:

```
publicPath:  '/dist/'
```

instead absolute path.

At second, if you use es6 syntax for export module:

```
export default Facility;
```

you should write your import code like this:

```
require.ensure([], function(require) {
  Facility = require('./Facility').default;
  ReactDOM.render(<Facility/>, document.getElementById('app'));
}, 'facility');
```

Or just to use commonjs syntax:

```
module.exports = Facility;
```

and then

```
require.ensure([], function(require) {
  Facility = require('./Facility');
  ReactDOM.render(<Facility/>, document.getElementById('app'));
}, 'facility');
```

See also: http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel-commonjs.html

**Update:**
You can set publicPath in your entry js file. For example:

*entry.js*

```
__webpack_public_path__ = '/publicPathToChunk/';

var chunk;
require.ensure([], function(require) { 
  chunk = require('./chunk'); 
}, 'chunk');
```

Also, you can use next trick:

```
var bundleSrc = document.querySelector('[src*="bundle"]').getAttribute("src");
__webpack_public_path__ = bundleSrc.substr(0, bundleSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: It does not work, Sorry. I have to use require.ensure to create the App chunk not only require for the import

Comment: Thanks it work, only one problem occurred...`bundle.js?ver=1.11:1Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/.../facility.bundle.js` when I try to Reload page but works normal if it's starts from a link.

Comment: `componentDidMount(){
        var Facility;
        require.ensure([], function(require) {
            Facility = require('./Facility').default;
            render(<Facility/>, document.getElementById('fl'));
        }, 'facility');
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <div id="fl"></div>`

Comment: Have you fixed your publicPath property? Do you use any server (e.g. webpack-dev-server)?

Comment: yes. I think that i need `__webpack_public_path__ in runtime` (don't know how to do it) because all this done for the wp plugin.  Do you have any experience how to implement it?

Comment: I've added how you can init publicPath in runtime